# DDD folder structure: split repositories in different folders or keep all business rules in a generic folder?

Tags: domain-driven-design, directory-structure

Let's say I have a bunch of integrations that uses to abstract modules: `parser` and `ordering`.

How would you say is the better approach for organizing the folder structure in a DDD point of view?

```
ordering/
----abstract.py
parser/
----abstract.py
integration1/
----ordering.py  # depends on ordering.abstract
----parser.py  # depends on parser.abstract
integration2/
----ordering.py  # depends on ordering.abstract
----parser.py  # depends on parser.abstract
```

OR

```
ordering/
----abstract.py
----integration1.py  # depends on abstract
----integration2.py  # depends on abstract
parser/
----abstract.py
----integration1.py  # depends on abstract
----integration2.py  # depends on abstract
```

The abstract files handles the business rules of my application (how we validate data, how we orchestrate the request-response cycle, etc.) and the integration files handles the business rules of the third parties (how we interpret the data they send, how we prepare the data in a way they expect, etc.).

The way I see, each integration acts as some sort of repository which it's core implementation relies on `abstract.py`.

I'm inclined for the first approach since we clearly separate these domains, but at the same time all files have the same purpose.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here: using abstractions in the domain layer and integrating external contexts.

### Abstractions in the domain layer

> The abstract files handles the business rules of my application (how we validate data, how we orchestrate the request-response cycle, etc.)

Constituting the domain layer (or package) only of abstractions (i.e. interfaces in other languages, you need to find the Python analogue for it) of its *dependencies* and injecting their concrete implementations from different packages is a good practice. That keeps the domain layer independent of infrastructures. There is an architectural pattern promoting this practice called the *port and adapter architecture*. Your first proposal somewhat connotes this pattern.

Additionally, in DDD, most of the business rules are enforced by the primary constructs: *aggregate roots* (the most prominent entities in the domain), *entities*, and *value objects*. All of these are implemented as concrete types, no need to abstract them away. Dependencies like *repositories*, *domain services*, etc. are abstracted.

Here follows a potential directory scheme, open to modifications of course, respecting the conventions I mentioned:

```
.
../domain
..../model
....../entity1
....../value object 1
....../entity2
..../services
....../service1 (interface)
....../service2 (interface)
..../repositories
....../repository1 (interface)
....../repository2 (interface)
../port
..../adapter
....../services
......../service1 (concrete)
......../service2 (concrete)
....../repositories
......../repository1 (concrete)
......../repository2 (concrete)
```

### Integrating external contexts

> ... and the integration files handles the business rules of the third parties (how we interpret the data they send, how we prepare the data in a way they expect, etc.)

Integrating external contexts (*context mapping* in DDD terminology) itself is a challenge. The *strategic* part of DDD deals with this issue and recommends several options for integrating contexts depending on the nature of the relationship between them. All the options strive to ensure that communication with external contexts go through some *translation process*; external contexts must *not infiltrate unchecked.*

> The way I see, each integration acts as some sort of repository which it's core implementation relies on abstract.py.

In DDD, *repository* is meant to retrieve and modify aggregate roots. *Some* of your translations do fit well into the repository pattern and you can model them after it. However, some of them may fit better into *domain services*. Just as any other repositories and domain services, you may put the abstractions of the integration ones in the domain package and their implementation in a different one.

Comment: Hey @Farhan Nasim, thanks for answering. The abstractions are not in the domain layer, I just simulate a small piece of the structure for the sake of simplicity. All the files I wrote about relies on (almost) only primitives so no infrastructure is coupled there (except some of the third parties but it's out of our control).

"However, some of them may fit better into domain services" -> What would you take in consideration to conclude such thing?

Thanks again!

Comment: Some integrations might _involve imposing business rules based on one or more other aggregates_ in the domain. A domain service can hold the aggregates' repository, fetch the aggregate wherever necessary, call and translate the external service, and check the business rule. A repository, on the other hand, fetches and stores _only one aggregate_, thus suitable for _data source like_ external services.